# Are prayers valid if I don't understand what the imam is reciting?

Tags: salat, arabic

Like after reading surat al-fatiha you would then read another verse in every rak'ah but I don't know arabic, I am currently learning the 4 quls. So if I go to the masjid and the imam is reciting other verses in arabic then obviously I won't understand what they are saying. So do I just stay in silent during this time clueless to what is being said or should I recite a verse that I know while he is reading his own verse?

And is there any point of me attending taraweeh prayer because I don't know arabic or the ayahs they readout?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/131788/is-it-permissible-to-read-the-quraan-without-understanding-its-meanings) fatwa. It is perfectly permissible to **read** Quran without understanding. Listening to Quran is also permissible according to [this](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/150633/will-he-be-rewarded-for-listening-to-the-quraan-without-understanding-it) fatwa. You are not the one who is reading the Quran in Salaah, it is the Imam. He reads with understanding. All you need to do is follow.

If in the future you decide that you want to learn the meanings then that too is perfectly fine. In fact, it's even better for you as you will understand what is being said.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the recitation of the Imam is not a condition for the validity of prayer according to any of the mazaahib as far as I know.

The benefit of attending taraweeh is to fulfill the Sunnah of the Prophet (SAW) and to listen to the recitation of the Quran.

Allah says:

> And We send down of the Qur'an that which is healing and mercy for the believers, but it does not increase the wrongdoers except in loss. (17:82)

But, it is definitely very recommended for you to learn Arabic such that you understand the Quran when it is recited.

Allah knows best.